# Sticky State with Lightning Override of New Button

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have overridden the New button of an object with an LWC (dutifully wrapped in an aura component):

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride" access="global">
    <c:loadConfiguration/>
</aura:component>
```

However, sporadically when I click the New button, the last instance of the LWC is displayed, with the previous data entered.

If I click around the UI a lot before clicking New again, this gets flushed, but obviously this is not a solution.

Anyone know why the previous instance of the LWC seems to be stuck in memory from the previous New button click and needs to be pushed out of some mystery cache somewhere by sufficient navigation?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you call an Apex method in your lwc component? Does this method have the Cacheable=true annotation?

Comment: Yes and yes.  But the manually entered data is not coming back from @wire functions as it is a New record LWC.  I have no issue with reference data being cached for a New button invocation.  It's the manually entered data that is also caching....

Comment: And why wouldn't the Salesforce architecture recognize that a New button override would not be an appropriate place to do caching?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with our component overrides and the solution that worked was to refresh the view of the aura component itself. It could add a little time to the page load but was the only workaround I could get to.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.reInit}" />
    <c:loadConfiguration/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
reInit: function (component, event, helper) {
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I had borrowed this code from somewhere else which I can't remember now to credit them.

Comment: Thanks, Naga,  I will give that a shot.

Comment: Hi Naga, I used your solution. However on mobile device it's not working as expected. Did you have this issue on mobile device ? Is there any other work around

Comment: I haven't tried this on mobile devices @Badduboy.